# My app keeps crashing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm currently working on a timer app in Android Studio and it keeps crashing before I can even run it. I need to have it done tonight so it can be my dad's Christmas present (it is for his company).

Here is my code:

```js
public class TimerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    TextView txtTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);
       // btnStart.setBackgroundColor(0x57C173);

        final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long secondsRemaining = millisUntilFinished / 60;
                long minutesRemaining = secondsRemaining / 60;
                secondsRemaining = secondsRemaining % 60;

                txtTimer.setText(minutesRemaining + ":" + secondsRemaining);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                txtTimer.setText("You are Awesome!");
            }
        };

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timer.start();
                btnStart.setText("Cancel");

                btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        timer.cancel();
                        btnStart.setText("Start");
                        txtTimer.setText("1:00");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is what my Logcat says:

```html
12-24 14:48:01.324  16878-16878/com.mintemovement.minutemovement W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416a9e30)
12-24 14:48:01.334  16878-16878/com.mintemovement.minutemovement E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mintemovement.minutemovement, PID: 16878
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mintemovement.minutemovement/com.mintemovement.minutemovement.TimerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1952)
            at com.mintemovement.minutemovement.TimerActivity.<init>(TimerActivity.java:12)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2348)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1952)
            at com.mintemovement.minutemovement.TimerActivity.<init>(TimerActivity.java:12)

Comment: You're trying to use findView before you even set the content view.

Comment: Now I feel stupid but it worked so that's good. Thanks ElefantPhace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public class TimerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button btnStart;
TextView txtTimer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);
   // btnStart.setBackgroundColor(0x57C173);
   btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
   txtTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
```